# Finding the correct implementation in C++ code

Tags: c++, debugging, apt

On [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247088/) someone noticed, that `apt-get install -y` does not ask questions (as expected) but seems to read from *stdin* anyways.

I was curious and tried to understand what that reading is good for.
Therefore I took an Ubuntu box and fetched the code with `apt-get source apt`.

For debugging I inserted a few lines of debugging output and build everything with `debuild -b -uc -us`, and installed the result.

Doing so I could track down the code to pretty much [this line](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/e6f0c9bca4b052d20a2e48ce9715b89e187b671a/apt-private/private-install.cc#L343) (not sure if I fetched exactly the right commit for the link) where `PM->DoInstall(status_fd)` is called.

Where exactly is that method defined? I only found a definition in [packagemanager.cc](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/e6f0c9bca4b052d20a2e48ce9715b89e187b671a/apt-pkg/packagemanager.cc#L1096) (and grepping for `nstall(int` did not show anything good, too), but added debugging output there is not printed. Therefore I assume I missed the correct implementation for the call above.

From the regular output the next thing I see is output of dpkg (and the eating of *stdin* in between) but I cannot find the code that is run by DoInstall, which at the end calls dpkg.

Question:

- What is the right procedure to find the definition of some method like above?
- Is there a better way to verify my guess than adding debug output?
- Did I miss anything else?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to verify my guess than adding debug output?

You could run the `apt-get` in the background and, after it has been suspended by `SIGTTIN`, attach `gdb` and inspect the `backtrace`.